# Android getApplicationMemory() returns incorrect value?

Tags: android

According to [Android 4.2 specification(Block 3.7)](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/ru//compatibility/4.2/android-4.2-cdd.pdf) :

```
Device implementations MUST configure Dalvik to allocate memory in accordance
with the upstream Android platform, and as specified by the following table. (See
Section 7.1.1 for screen size and screen density definitions.)
Note that memory values specified below are considered minimum values, and device
implementations MAYallocate more memory per application.

<--Table of memory usage-->
xlarge xhdpi 128MB
```

I want to know what the free available memory of my application. 
NOT ON DEVICE!

> I use a largeHeap=true

#### Why I need to know this?

I use a mechanism that allows to me check fit Bitmap in memory or no.

```
//ref:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073744/android-how-to-check-how-much-memory-is-remaining
public static double availableMemoryMB(Activity activity) {
    ActivityManager.MemoryInfo mi = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
    long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;

    // old solution
    // double max = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024;
    // Debug.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new Debug.MemoryInfo();
    // Debug.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
    return availableMegs;
}

public static final long SAFETY_MEMORY_BUFFER = 10;//MB

public static boolean canBitmapFitInMemory(Activity activity, String path) {
    System.gc();
    long size = getBitmapSizeWithoutDecoding(path);
    Log.d("image MB:" + size);
    return size <= availableMemoryMB(activity) - SAFETY_MEMORY_BUFFER;
}
```

My Image size is 104 MB. Available memory is 286 MB. And I still getting OutOfMemoryError.

Maybe I check not an application memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And I still getting OutOfMemoryError.

You are checking to see if the sum of all free memory blocks is enough to hold your bitmap. You will get an `OutOfMemoryError` if there is no *single* free memory block big enough to hold your bitmap.

Android does not have a moving garbage collector (except on Android 5.0+, and then only when your app is in the background). As a result, your heap will become fragmented, where the largest available free block is far smaller than the sum of all available free blocks.

You are certainly welcome to use an algorithm like you have in your question as a starting point. However, the longer your process is around, the more likely it is that your algorithm will return a value that is far too high. You will need to handle the `OutOfMemoryError` and try again with a smaller bitmap size. Or, come up with a new approach to your problem altogether.

For example, a 104MB image, if square, would be 5221 pixels on a side. I know of no Android screen that is anywhere near that big. It is pointless to load a bitmap that is larger than the screen. If your objective is to allow pinch-zoom or something to be able to zoom in, that's fine, but then use something [like `SubsamplingScaleImageView`](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) to avoid having the entire bitmap in memory at once.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Can you give me some link for read about how Android Garbage works?

Comment: @ssh: Unfortunately, there isn't a lot on it in official documentation. I have [a conference video](https://commonsware.com/videos) on memory management that gets into it.