# How to overcome from OutOfMemoryError in android

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory

Each and everytime I use swipe option to swipe b/w Images I always get `OutOfMemoryError`. Either I am using `ViewPager` or `ActivitySwipeDetector` every time this error occured. I am using `android:largeHeap="true"` its work on API level 11 and above. But what to do if we are using minimum API level 8. And what guidelines we have to follow for elminating this error and working with lots of bitmaps?

Comment: This question is as broad as the moon. Try these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544919/android-how-to-handle-out-of-memory-exception https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: Check these - https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html, http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html, http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions to avoid OOM in ViewPager.

- If the bitmap sizes for the image views in your view pager are very big, then dynamically resize the bitmap based on the screen size.
- Call bitmap.recycle() in the [destroyItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#destroyItem%28android.view.ViewGroup,%20int,%20java.lang.Object%29) method of view pager adapter to free up memory (ginger bread devices). If you have not implemented destroyItem correctly, then it could lead to memory issues.
- Set [setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) to a small value (say 2) to minimize the number of bitmaps.