# How to handle out of memory exceptions in android

Tags: android

am getting out of memory exception while loading image

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "/Omoto Images/background image.jpg";
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        page4image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

above code is for loading image from internal storage

Comment: What is the size of the image? What is the exact memory error from the logcat?

Comment: your image siz too large... post your logcat..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android how to handle out of memory exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544919/android-how-to-handle-out-of-memory-exception)

Comment: Better is use Bitmap.Options RGB565 format, because it reduces size of image in 2 times. More, if it's needed, use sampling in options.

Comment: [USE THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45632208/7616371) for solve this type error in android

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the heap memory of the application by using the **largeheap="true"** in AndroidManifest.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true">

  </application>
```

But, it is not good practice to use it unless it is needed.

Official doc states

Whether your application's processes should be created with a large Dalvik heap. This applies to all processes created for the application. 
It only applies to the first application loaded into a process; if you're using a shared user ID to allow multiple applications to use a process, they all must use this option consistently or they will have unpredictable results. 
Most apps should not need this and should instead focus on reducing their overall memory usage for improved performance. Enabling this also does not guarantee a fixed increase in available memory, because some devices are constrained by their total available memory.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't handle the OutOfMemory exception. The good explanation is described here: [Catching java.lang.OutOfMemoryError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679330/catching-java-lang-outofmemoryerror)