# Out of memory exception issue

Tags: android, performance-testing

I am getting out of memory exception randomly , I am downloading heavy images in my project from AWS. how to solve the issue

```
[369][4/29/2011 18:32:15:343]-ERR -[ThreadId = 7916, UIFramework_ICEVisionPro_GUIExceptionHandler.LogException]-System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.

   at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHdcInternal(IntPtr hdc)

   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.CreateBuffer(IntPtr src, Int32 offsetX, Int32 offsetY, Int32 width, Int32 height)

   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.AllocBuffer(Graphics targetGraphics, IntPtr targetDC, Rectangle targetRectangle)

   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.AllocBufferInTempManager(Graphics targetGraphics, IntPtr targetDC, Rectangle targetRectangle)

   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.Allocate(IntPtr targetDC, Rectangle targetRectangle)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
```

Comment: Add some code in it, that what have tried..

Comment: `how to solve the issue` depends on how you download them, and what you do with them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544919/how-to-handle-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: Use Glide lib for setting bitmap to imageview

Answer (score -2):

compress the downloaded bitmap as below

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());
myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);

Here 100 meaning compress for max quality.

Comment: That's not going to help.  That writes it to disk.  It does not compress the amount of memory used to store it in RAM for drawing.