# Android Error java.lang.OutOfMemory: Failed to allocate

Tags: java, android

I am getting this error every time I try to upload a picture in my app.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 38937612 byte allocation with 9459304 free bytes and 9MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:635)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:611)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:649)
        at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.getBitmap(MediaStore.java:867)
        at com.example.laundry1app.AddProductActivity.onActivityResult(AddProductActivity.java:192)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6470)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3716)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3763)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1403)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Below is  my code for the 'AddProductActivity' which is showing the error. Please rectify it or let me know what is the problem here so that I can work upon it.

```
package com.example.laundry1app;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;

public class AddProductActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText english;
    private Spinner category;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private ImageButton product;
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://laundryapp-f9f1c.appspot.com/").child("products");
    int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 111;
    Uri filePath;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_product);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Uploading....");
        product = findViewById(R.id.img);
        product.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            }
        });
        english = findViewById(R.id.english);
//        quantity = findViewById(R.id.quantity);
//        price = findViewById(R.id.price);
//        unit = findViewById(R.id.unit);
        category = findViewById(R.id.category);
        Button add = findViewById(R.id.add);
//        ArrayList<String> units = new ArrayList<>();
//        units.add("Select");
//        units.add("kg");
//        units.add("gm");
//        ArrayAdapter<String> unitsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Objects.requireNonNull(getBaseContext()), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, units);
//        unitsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
//        unit.setAdapter(unitsAdapter);
        ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
        categories.add("Select");
        categories.add("Wash and Press");
        categories.add("Dry Clean");
        ArrayAdapter<String> categoriesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Objects.requireNonNull(getBaseContext()), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
        categoriesAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        category.setAdapter(categoriesAdapter);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Objects.equals(english.getText().toString(), "")) {
                    english.requestFocus();
                    english.setError("This Is A Required Field");
                } //else if (Objects.equals(quantity.getText().toString(), "")) {
//                    quantity.requestFocus();
//                    quantity.setError("This Is A Required Field");
//                } else if (Objects.equals(unit.getSelectedItem().toString(), "Select")) {
//                    unit.performClick();
//                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Select Unit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                } else if (Objects.equals(price.getText().toString(), "")) {
//                    price.requestFocus();
//                    price.setError("This Is A Required Field");}
                else if (Objects.equals(category.getSelectedItem().toString(), "Select")) {
                    category.performClick();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Select Category", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    if (Objects.equals(category.getSelectedItem().toString(), "Wash and Press")) {
                        if(filePath != null) {
                            pd.show();
                            StorageReference childRef = storageRef.child("products").child(english.getText().toString());
                            UploadTask uploadTask = childRef.putFile(filePath);
                            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                    storageRef.child("products/" + english.getText().toString()).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                            pd.dismiss();
                                            reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("products").push();
                                            reference.child("english").setValue(english.getText().toString());
//                                            reference.child("hindi").setValue(hindi.getText().toString());
//                                            reference.child("quantity").setValue(quantity.getText().toString() + " " + unit.getSelectedItem().toString());
//                                            reference.child("price").setValue(Long.parseLong(price.getText().toString()));
                                            reference.child("image").setValue(uri.toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Product Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        if (getFragmentManager() != null) {
                                                            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AdminDashboardActivity.class));
                                                            finish();
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Upload Failed -> " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Select an image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else if (Objects.equals(category.getSelectedItem().toString(), "dryclean")) {
                        if(filePath != null) {
                            pd.show();
                            StorageReference childRef = storageRef.child("dryclean").child(english.getText().toString());
                            UploadTask uploadTask = childRef.putFile(filePath);
                            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                    storageRef.child("dryclean/" + english.getText().toString()).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                            pd.dismiss();
                                            reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("dryclean").push();
                                            reference.child("english").setValue(english.getText().toString());
//                                            reference.child("hindi").setValue(hindi.getText().toString());
//                                            reference.child("quantity").setValue(quantity.getText().toString() + " " + unit.getSelectedItem().toString());
//                                            reference.child("price").setValue(Long.parseLong(price.getText().toString()));
                                            reference.child("image").setValue(uri.toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Product Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        if (getFragmentManager() != null) {
                                                            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AdminDashboardActivity.class));
                                                            finish();
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Upload Failed -> " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Select an image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                product.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AdminDashboardActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AuthenticationActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AuthenticationActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AuthenticationActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting a way out of this and this is my first time using this. Requesting for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544919/how-to-handle-outofmemoryerror)

Answer (score 1):

Your image that you are trying to load is far too large, both for your available memory and for the screen size. Plus, you are loading the image on the main application thread, so your UI will be frozen while all of that I/O is going on.

So, replace your current image-loading logic in `onActivityResult()` with an image-loading library, such as [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/getting-started.html) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso). Both of these will be able to load the image at a lower resolution (to fit the size of your `ImageView`) and do the work on a background thread.